# What is the difference between these two strings?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, gcc

**PART 1**

I have 2 strings and they are defined in following ways-

```
char s1[] = "foo";
char *s2 = "foo";
```

When I try to change a character of these strings, say, the 2nd character -

```
char s1[1] = 'x';
char s2[1] = 'x';
```

the character in string `s1` changes, but changing the character in string `s2` gives me this error - `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Why is it so?

Why am I unable to change the character of the string which is defined in the other way?

---

**PART 2**

Strings (they are array of characters, right?) can be initialized using - `char *s = "foo"`
but why does compiler gives warnings when I try to initialize arrays of different type using the same thing like `int *arr = {1, 2, 3}`?

```
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:5:5: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
foo.c:5:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘foo’) [enabled by default]
foo.c:5:5: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
foo.c:5:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘foo’) [enabled by default]
foo.c:5:5: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
foo.c:5:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘foo’) [enabled by default]
```

---

**NOTE:** My compiler is GCC.

Comment: **`s1` is an array** (with 4 elements); **`s2` is a pointer** (to the first element of an (un-modifiable) array with 4 elements). A "string" is an array where one of it's elements is `'\0'`. Read the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), starting with section 6.

Comment: @KingsIndian There is a **PART 2** also.

Comment: @pmg It doesn't have to be "un-modifiable". Only modifying it is UB. There's a subtle difference.

Comment: @KingsIndian: I mean "un-modifiable under penalty of UB". The point being that, unlike what some people thing, **in C**, a string literal is not a constant: it is of type `char [N] /* with N large enough for all elements and the nul byte */`, not `const char[N]`. Note I didn't say "const" (or "constant") for that reason :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is a string that is an array of characters, filled with the characters in the string "foo", the second one is a pointer to a constant with the value "foo". Since the second one is constant, it isn't allowed to modify it.

And no, you can't initialize a pointer to set of values - because the pointer has no actual memory to store the values assigned to it. You need to either make it point to another array:

```
int foox[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *foo = foox;
```

or you need to allocate some memory, and then store the values:

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

foo[0] = 1; 
foo[1] = 2; 
foo[2] = 3;
```

Comment: So can I call such strings immutable?

Comment: That standard says that it is "undefined behaviour" to write to them - it's entirely possible that you can write to such a string in some circumstances [e.g. using Turbo C++, you probably could, because it generates code for DOS, which doesn't have any ability to write-protect memory, so there's nothing to stop you from writing to the string - or overwriting the code you are currently executing, should you write code that does that, intentionally or otherwise].